# How to make JUnit4 + Hamcrest 1.3 + Mockito work from Eclipse AND Tycho

Tags: eclipse, junit, mockito, tycho, hamcrest

I've managed to get **JUnit 4.12** + **Hamcrest 1.3** + **Mockito 2.8.47** to work in *Eclipse* so that when I add them as dependencies, my tests will run.

(The way I've done this is using the [p2-maven-plugin](https://github.com/reficio/p2-maven-plugin/) to bundle the following
artifacts from Maven Central into plugins/a feature and provide them via P2:

- `junit 4.12`
- `org.mockito.mockito-core 2.8.47`
- `org.hamcrest.all 1.3.0`

Adding the plugins to my test fragment as dependencies makes the tests
run in Eclipse.

However, the *Tycho* build of the same fragment will fail with the
following messages:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/hamcrest/Matcher" 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:273)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:632)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:586)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:538)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:525)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:12)
at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:956)
at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:923)
```

So it seems that some other plugin is loading the package
`org.hamcrest.Matcher` **before** my fragment does. This is probably due
to the import/export/partial import/partial export chaos surrounding the
JUnit/Hamcrest/Mockito setup.

Does anyone have an idea -- or even better: a working example -- of how to
get the three components work together both within the IDE (for quick
checks on whether tests run) and Tycho (for checks during the build)?

Comment: I think Mockito 2.8.47 already have hamcrest.

Comment: I get the error on a test fragment with dependencies on just Hamcrest and JUnit though.

Comment: I think you are right in that the source of the problem is the export chaos around JUnit/Hamcrest/Mockito. The p2-maven-plugin is likely to generate misleading MANIFESTs. Can you add a minimal project to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I am successfully using JUnit 4.12, Hamcrest 1.3, and **Mockito 1.9.5** in several projects. For example here: https://github.com/rherrmann/eclipse-extras The bundles are retrieved from Orbit. Not sure what changed in Mockito in the meanwhile, However, you may want to compare your manifests with those from Orbit in order to find the wrong import or export statement,

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that the loader want the dependencies in a bundle.

But I guess you haven't put your test lib in a bundle.

You could try to add them in the dependencies of your product to see how it reacts.

Answer (score 0):

**Background**

The root of the problem is, that `org.junit` already has a dependency to `org.hamcrest.core`. So when your test-plugins has a dependency to `org.hamcrest.all` (which contains everything of hamcrest-core and all other hamcrest artifacts), all classes specified in hamcrest-core exist twice. Once in the bundle of hamcrest-core and once in hamcrest-all, which is why you get the linkage error.

If you open the Manifest of `org.junit` in the Manifest-Editor of Eclipse and go to the 'Dependencies' tab it should show you `org.hamcreast.core` in the "Required Plug-ins" section and `org.hamcreast.core` should be re-exported. Or in the raw-manifest it should look like this:

```
Require-Bundle: org.hamcrest.core;bundle-version="1.3.0";visibility:=reexport
```

**Solution 1 - add hamcrest sub-modules**

Instead of adding the all hamcrest-modul containing `hamcrest.all` as dependency to my Eclipse test-bundle/project (via 'Require-Bundle'), I add the hamcrest sub-modules that I require, except for hamcrest-core (because it is already re-exported in my case). For me hamcrest-library was sufficient.

The available hamcrest sub-modules are (according to the org.hamcrest:hamcrest-parent pom, which can be found here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-parent/1.3/hamcrest-parent-1.3.pom):

- hamcrest-core
- hamcrest-library
- hamcrest-generator
- hamcrest-integration

**Creating the p2-Repo containing the required bundles**

When using Maven and the 'org.reficio:p2-maven-plugin' to build the p2-repo that contains the mentioned test-bundles, the conversion of the maven-artifacts to OSGi-bundles does not produce fully working results by default.
Converting a maven-module to a full OSGi-bundle consists mainly of configuring the MANIFEST.MF to contain proper entries. For this the p2-maven-plugin utilizes "bnd tool".
By default the Java packages provided by all maven dependencies of a maven module are added as optional `Imported-package` when that module is converted into a OSGi-bundle.

In my case this had the consequence that the `org.hamcrest.library` bundle refereed to the packages from hamcrest-core only via `Import-Package` in its MANIFEST.MF.
But unfortunately with only this specified, the Equinox-ClassLoader did not find the classes from hamcrest-core in the test-runtime and threw a corresponding exception. Maybe this is also caused by the fact that hamcrest-core and hamcrest-library have a package "org.hamcrest" and bnd-tools adds the exported packages of a bundle to the imported packages again.

The solution in my case was to instruct the `org.reficio:p2-maven-plugin` respectively bnd-tools to add `org.hamcrest.core` as "Require-Bundle" to the Manifest of hamcrest-library. For this, the instructions-element shown below needs to be add to the artifact-element of `org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library` in the execution-configuration of the 'p2-maven-plugin' in the `pom.xml` used to build the p2-repo:

```
        <artifact>
          <id>org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3</id>
          <instructions>
            <Require-Bundle>org.hamcrest.core</Require-Bundle>
          </instructions>
        </artifact>
```

If hamcrest sub-modules other than hamcrest-library are are used, the instructions need to be analogous, corresponding to the dependencies listed in their pom.

**Edit**
Eclipse Orbit provides `org.hamcrest.library`, `org.hamcrest.integrator` and `org.hamcrest.generator` bundles that have have org.hamcrest.core as required bundle (if necessary):
https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/

**Appendix**
In the end first solution caused a SecurityException:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.hamcrest.Matchers"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

Which is a known issue. The following two solutions avoid this issue and work properly during Tycho builds and from within Eclipse.

**Solution 2 - bundle hamcrest sub-module jars with a plug-in**
Another approach is to download the jar of the required hamcrest sub-module and bundle it with a Eclipse plugin directly, like it is described here:
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Hamcrest/article.html#hamcrest_eclipse

To bundle the jar with a plug-in, include it in the project and add it to the plug-ins classpath. Go to the Runtime-Tab of the Manifest-Editor and klick `Add...` in the Classpath section and select the jar. This should add the jar to the .classpath, MANIFEST.MF and build.properties file properly.
Make sure the jar is included before the other plug-in dependencies (which include hamcrest-core), as stated in the mentioned tutorial.

If hamcrest should be used in multiple test-projects/fragments, add the jar to a test plug-in all other test-projects depend on.

**Solution 3 - use org.hamcrest 2.x**
Since hamcrest-2 there is only one org.hamcrest jar/artifact that includes everything from hamcrest. Using hamcrest 2 avoids all the issues and is my preferred solution. Except for the changed packaing of hamcrest the API did not break, so it should be sufficient to just include org.hamcrest:
https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/releases/tag/v2.1

In order to create a p2-repo that includes `org.hamcrest`-2.2 the following sippet has to be included into the `configuration`-`artifacts` element of the `p2-maven-plugin` execution in the pom.xml:

```
        <artifact>
          <id>org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:2.2</id>
          <instructions>
            <Require-Bundle>org.hamcrest;bundle-version="2.2.0";visibility:=reexport</Require-Bundle>
          </instructions>
        </artifact>
        <artifact>
          <id>org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2</id>
        </artifact>
```

The IUs `org.hamcrest.core` 2.2 and `org.hamcrest` have to be included in the target-platform to make them available for plug-ins in Eclipse and during. All plug-ins which depend on `org.junit` now have `org.hamcrest` also available.

This aproach works because `org.hamcrest.core` still exists in version 2 stream, even tough it is deprected and empty. Its only purpose is to redirect build-systems to the new `org.hamcrest`-2.x jar/artifact. Therefore `org.hamcrest.core`-2.2 specifies a compile dependency to
`org.hamcrest`-2.2 in its pom.xml. Unfortunately the `p2-maven-plugin` dosn't translate it directly into a bundle-requirement for org.hamcrest in the manifest, but with the sippet above enforces that.

Because `org.junit` requires the bundle org.hamcrest.core with a minimal version of 1.3 (but without upper-bound) it uses the present `org.hamcrest.core`-2.2 . `org.hamcrest.core`-2.2 again requires `org.hamcrest`-2.2 and re-exports it. This makes `org.junit` use `org.hamcrest`-2.2 in the end and because org.junit re-exports `hamcrest-core` it also provides `org.hamcrest`-2.2 immediately to all depended plug-ins.

**Note**
If you want to play around with different variants of a jar, don't forget to clear (means delete on the drive) the bundle pools of Maven (in `<your-home>/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/` and Eclipse PDE (in `<your-workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/`) in between. Otherwise you will always use the first one, because jar's with the same version are not updated.